# PowerShell search for text and adding a line

Tags: powershell

Sorry for the long post.  Wanted to explain in detail.
I'm trying to achieve three things and very nearly there.  Probably a school boy error.  Tried nested loops etc but could not get it working.

It appears I need to split the `$resultszone` array.

1. Search for specific areas within file.  In the example below, it's the section after `\zones\`, test1.in-addr.arpa, test2.in-addr.arpa, etc.
2. Copy and trim content after area found.  In first example, just test1.in-addr.arpa (Removing the beginning "\" and end "]"
3. Add a line including the area found (example test1.in-addr.arpa), to below the line containing "Type".

Example source file:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server\Zones\test1.in-addr.arpa]
"Type"=dword:00000001
"SecureSecondaries"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server\Zones\test2.in-addr.arpa]
"Type"=dword:00000001
"SecureSecondaries"=dword:00000002
```

Expected result

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server\Zones\test1.in-addr.arpa]
"Type"=dword:00000001
"DatabaseFile"="test1.in-addr.arpa.dns"
"SecureSecondaries"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server\Zones\test2.in-addr.arpa]
"Type"=dword:00000001
"DatabaseFile"="test2.in-addr.arpa.dns"
"SecureSecondaries"=dword:00000002
```

I've managed to achieve all using the code below, except it adds a line including all the results from area found, for every section.

For example:

```
"DatabaseFile"="test1.in-addr.arpa test2.in-addr.arpa
```

```
#Get FileName Path
$FileName = "C:\temp\test.conf"

#Search for pattern in file and trim to desired format.
#Store array in  $resultsZone
$resultszone = Select-String -Path "c:\temp\test.conf" -Pattern '(?<=Zones)(.*)' |
    select -expa matches |
    select -expa value |
    % { $_.Trim("\]") }

# Get contents of file
(Get-Content $FileName) | ForEach-Object {
    #Start Loop to find area of File to insert line
    $_ # send the current line to output
    if ($_ -match "type") {
        #Add Line after the selected pattern (type) including area trimmed
        """DatabaseFile" + """=""" + $resultszone + ".dns" + """"
    }
} | Set-Content C:\temp\elctest.conf
```

Comment: Registry files use INI format, so I'd recommend parsing it as such. Please use the search box at the top of the page. Similar questions have been asked before.

Comment: Only being used as an input for a 3rd party solution.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this achieves what you're looking for:

```
$FileName = "C:\Temp\test.conf"

Get-Content $FileName | ForEach-Object {
    $Match = ($_ | Select-String -pattern '(?<=Zones\\)(.*)').matches.value

    if ($Match) { $LastMatch = ($Match).Trim("\]") }

    $_

    if ($LastMatch -and $_ -match 'type') {
        """DatabaseFile" + """=""" + $LastMatch + ".dns" + """"
    }
} | Set-Content C:\Temp\elctest.conf
```

The fix is that we do the `Select-String` within the loop against each line, and then store when it matches in another variable (named `$LastMatch`) so that when we reach the line where we want to insert the previous time it matched, we have it.

Comment: That's perfect Mark.  Thank you for your efforts and explanation.